# Change what variable C() drops in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to turn a single column of data into categorical data to run a regression. I've been using the c() operator.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
results2 = smf.ols('risk ~ age + sex + EQIP + CRP + C(educ) + C(sales)', data = data1_clean).fit()
print(results2.summary())
```

It automatically drops one of the categories but I want to drop a different category. The result is below.

```
                     coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept           4.7975      1.301      3.687      0.000       2.240       7.355
C(educ)[T.2.0]      0.3857      0.671      0.575      0.565      -0.932       1.704
C(educ)[T.3.0]      0.5958      0.681      0.875      0.382      -0.742       1.934
C(educ)[T.4.0]      0.7399      0.700      1.057      0.291      -0.636       2.116
C(educ)[T.5.0]      0.7908      0.699      1.131      0.258      -0.583       2.164
C(educ)[T.6.0]      1.2349      0.733      1.684      0.093      -0.206       2.676
C(sales)[T.2.0]     0.6658      0.270      2.469      0.014       0.136       1.196
C(sales)[T.3.0]     1.2227      0.296      4.127      0.000       0.641       1.805
C(sales)[T.4.0]     0.7465      0.317      2.353      0.019       0.123       1.370
C(sales)[T.5.0]     1.0778      0.271      3.974      0.000       0.545       1.611
age                -0.0116      0.007     -1.642      0.101      -0.025       0.002
sex                 0.4639      0.495      0.937      0.349      -0.509       1.437
EQIP                0.4884      0.249      1.959      0.051      -0.001       0.978
CRP                -0.0357      0.197     -0.181      0.857      -0.423       0.352
==============================================================================
```

How do I change which category is dropped?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood the question correctly `drop_cols` parameter define columns to drop from the design matrix, cannot be used to drop terms involving categoricals.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"y": [1, 2, 3], "x": [1, 2, 3], "z": [1, 2, 3], 'drop': [1, 2, 3]}, index=[1, 2, 3])
data1_clean =  data
results2 = smf.ols('y ~ C(x) + C(z) + C(drop)', data = data1_clean, drop_cols=['C(z)[T.3]']).fit()
print(results2.summary())
```

output:

```
================================================================================
                   coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept        1.0000        inf          0        nan         nan         nan
C(x)[T.2]        0.3333        inf          0        nan         nan         nan
C(x)[T.3]        1.0000        inf          0        nan         nan         nan
C(z)[T.2]        0.3333        inf          0        nan         nan         nan
C(drop)[T.2]     0.3333        inf          0        nan         nan         nan
C(drop)[T.3]     1.0000        inf          0        nan         nan         nan
```

it was dropped:

```
C(z)[T.3]        0.6667        inf          0        nan         nan         nan
```

Comment: what happened to c(z)[T.1]?

Comment: c (z) [T.1] has never been

Comment: Sorry, my follow up wasn't anywhere near specific enough. Can I add c(z)[T.1] back while also dropping c(Z)[T.3]? Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Can you append a part of your dataframe to question and name of category witch should be dropped?